# pytest not collecting test from other folders

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following file structure.

```
- tests
    -unit_tests
        - jobs
            - bronze
                - __init__.py
                - test_test.py
  __init__.py
  test_tradebook.py
  test_extract_bronze.py
  test_extract_silver.py
  test_load_bronze.py
  test_portfolio.py
  test_urlbuilder.py
```

[image]

As you can see the lone test is not runned.

So to summerize I have one test in `/tests/unit_tests/jobs/bronze` and all the other ones are in `/tests` now **pytest** does not seem to recognize this one lone test in my subfolders. The goal is to move all the other tests aswell. The command I use is `poetry run pytest`
All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to specify the directory where pytest will search for tests in the pytest.ini file in the `tests` folder: 
    [pytest]
    testpaths =
        unit_tests

Comment: Can you please share what you have inside your `test_test.py` file?

Comment: It's just a test to test the code there is not really much in this file